# C++ plugins, LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress needs the exported function in each implementation

Tags: c++, dllexport, visual-c++-2005

I want to create a plugin architecture. I have a DLL which will serve as the interface and I will then have multiple DLLs for each implementation.

### Normalizer.dll-interface DLL

#### Normalizer.hpp

```
class INormalizer {
  virtual ~INormalizer() { }
  virtual std::string Normalize(const std::string& input) = 0;
  virtual void Destroy() = 0;
}
```

#### NormalizerFactory.hpp

```
template<typename T> INormalizer* CreateT() { return new T; }

class NormalizerFactory {
public:
  typedef std::map<std::string, INormalizer*(*)()> map_type;
  static INormalizer* CreateInstance(const std::string& name) {
    map_type::iterator it = getMap()->find(name);
    if(it == getMap()->end()) {
      return NULL;
    }
    return it->second();
  }
protected:
  static map_type* getMap() {
    if(!_map) {
      _map = new map_type;
    }
    return _map;
  }
private:
  static map_type* _map;
}
```

#### NormalizerFactory.cpp

```
NormalizerFactory::map_type* NormalizerFactory::_map = NULL;
```

#### DerivedRegister.hpp

```
template<typename T>
class DerivedRegister : NormalizerFactory {
public:
  DerivedRegister(const std::string& name) {
    getMap()->insert(std::make_pair(name, &createT<T>));
  }
}
```

#### Normalizer.cpp

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) INormalizer* __cdecl CreateNormalizer(const std::string& name) {
  return NormalizerFactory::CreateInstance(name);
}
```

### Normalizer.AlphaNumericOnly.dll

#### AlphaNumericOnly.h

```
class AlphaNumericOnly : public INormalizer {
public:
  ~AlphaNumericOnly();
  std::string Normalize(const std::string& input) override;
  void Destroy() override;
private:
  static DerivedRegister<AlphaNumericOnly> _reg; 
}
```

#### AlphaNumericOnly.cpp

```
...
DerivedRegister<AlphaNumericOnly> AlphaNUmericOnly::_reg("AlphaNumericOnly");
```

- **Q** How can I force that each implementer also include the `DerivedRegister<T> _reg` member without adding to the `INormalizer` interface.
- **Q** When building AlphaNumericOnly.dll, the linker complains with [LNK2001](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2001?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(LNK2001)%26rd%3Dtrue) for `NormalizerFactory::_map`. I don't want to have to define the static member `NormalizerFactory::_map` in each implementation DLL.

The implementation DLLs will be consumed by `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress` in the client application. If I load AlphaNumericOnly.dll using `LoadLibrary` then the call to `GetProcAddress(hDll, "CreateNormalizer")` fails because the `CreateNormalizer` function is not exported in this DLL.

- **Q** Is there any way I can just create one export file and use it in all implementation DLLs and force all implementers to use this DEF file.

Comment: Are  you really using Visual C++ 2005?

Comment: @MichaelGeary unfortunately yes, the code must build with Visual C++ 2005.

Comment: This is pseudo-code, yes?  I wouldn't expect much success using the `override` keyword in VC++ 2005?

Comment: Passing non-POD types like `std::string` over DLL boundaries is really bad news. Don't do it. As for the linker error, move `_map` into a common DLL that the other DLLs use, and don't make it a `static` variable, define an exported function that the other DLLs can call to access it. But then you are back into the risky territory of passing non-POD objects over DLL boundaries again. You need to design your system so it is not dependent on passing around shared objects, just interfaces.